# What is the difference between "grub" and "grub2" in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, grub2

I have been exploring this website for my queries and many times I find stuff mentioned as

```
update-grub2
```

and

```
update-grub
```

Surprisingly, many of the things to be updated for grub2, I update in grub and it works. Then what is the difference between them (in Ubuntu 18.04)?

Comment: Welcome! Apparently, according to the man pages, they are the same command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same:

```
$ which update-grub
/usr/sbin/update-grub

$ which update-grub2
/usr/sbin/update-grub2

$ ls -la /usr/sbin/update-grub*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  64 veebr  6 19:20 /usr/sbin/update-grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  11 veebr  6 19:37 /usr/sbin/update-grub2 -> update-grub
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 301 märts 27  2015 /usr/sbin/update-grub-gfxpayload
```

`grub` is as legacy name (compatibility sake), `grub2` is already about 10 years main bootloader in Ubuntu

Comment: But when I use > update-grub2 < , the changes aren't listed...
Example-when I tried to set my windows partitions to auto-mount at startup.

Comment: Mounting partitions has nothing to do with `grub`, grub chooses which system to boot. Partitions are mounted **during** the system bootup (if they are set up to auto-mount).

Comment: Oh,I don't remember which file I edited or why I edited grub,Anyway thanks.